# Invalid property name in .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

```py
MDFloatLayout:

    MDGridLayout:
        size_hint = .5, .5
        pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
        cols = 3
        rows = 3

# Error this row
        Button:
            id: button1
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button1)
        Button:
            id: button2
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button2)
        Button:
            id: button3
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button3)
        Button:
            id: button4
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button4)
        Button:
            id: button5
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button5)
        Button:
            id: button6
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button6)
        Button:
            id: button7
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button7)
        Button:
            id: button8
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button8)
        Button:
            id: button9
            text:""
            font_size = "45sp"
            on_release: app.presser(button9)

    MDLabel:
        id: score
        font_size: "32sp"
        text: "X Goes First!"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_y": .3}

    MDRaiseButton:
        id: restart
        text: "Resat The Game"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
        on_release: app.restart()
```

Comment: First you should go through the guidelines for [asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site. However replacing `=` with `:` might work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.